# How to trigger an event from the SVG <switch>

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

I am having trouble with the switch element in SVG.
I would like to call Javascript functions in case the first option (a `ForeignElement` in this case) fails to build. My SVG:

```
<switch>
  <foreignObject .../>      
  <text font-size="10" font-family="Verdana">
    <tspan x="10" y="10"  onload="bailout()">Please use a w3c compliant browser.</tspan>
  </text>
</switch>
```

Firefox works as expected and handles the `foreignObject`. Chrome and Opera handle the `foreignObject` fine, but still trigger the `bailout()`. My question does not involve `foreignObject`. It concerns the switch itself. The standard says that switch does not make a difference to included script tags, so that is also not an option.

How could I trigger an event if the first option(s) in the switch fail?
Is there some event I can trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does not support onload except on outer SVG elements so it's a coincidence that you think it's working. If you put the text element first for instance you'd see that Firefox wouldn't run the onload then either.

Your main problem is that all elements in a switch are loaded, they need to be as they can still be referenced by things like `<use>`.

There's no easy way to do what you want; events won't work. In the past I've run getBBox on the switch to see how big it is and then used that to determine which thing is rendered.